# Showing image name when hovered over

Tags: html

I got the following codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{url}/app/tpl/skins/{skin}/hk/style/topstoryimages.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>News Images</title>
</head>
<body>

<center class="midden">

    <h1 class="titel">title</h1>
    <p>text<br>
    text</p>
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/1atap.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/1model.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/accesories.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/alhambra.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/alhambra2.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/art.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/AU_TS_TheTake_v1.jpg.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/AU_Winter.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Badgewidget_300x187.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/bakgrunder.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Bat_hulk_habbo.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/BeachBunny2.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/bigbro_ts1.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/bigbro_ts2.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/bigbro_ts3.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/bionicle_topStory_300x187v2.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Bolly_TopStoryScene2.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Bolly_TopStoryScene3.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/BollyTopStory_stage5.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/BRPT_TopStory_sabatina_300x187.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/BRPT_TopStory_Summer.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/CasinoTS.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Childline_Topstory.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/chiuhuahuatopstory.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/christmasbus.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/christmassanta.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Claireclarke.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Classicparade.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/creditspromo.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Diner_300x187_Topstory_dancefloor.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Diner_300x187_Topstory_enter.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Diner_300x187_Topstory_open.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Diner_300x187_Topstory_shakes.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Diner_300x187_Topstory_waitress.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/DK_dune_topstory.jpg" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/double_promo_topstory_300x187.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/easter.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/easter2.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/eating.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/envy_TopStory_300x187.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/ES_super_Top_story_New01.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/ES_super_Top_story_New02.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/ES_super_Top_story_New03.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/ES_super_Top_story_New04.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/ES_super_Top_story_New05.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/ES_super_Top_story_New06.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/exe_tstories_300x187.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/facebook.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/fatherhabbo_300x187_girl.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/festival1.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/festival2.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/festival3.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/festival4.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/festival5.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Footballevent.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/fotboll1.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/fotboll2.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/fotboll3.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/frank_topstory_300x187.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/getitcard.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/gym.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/H4D_Topstory.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/habbo_mall_topstory2.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Habbo_Rasmus_topstory.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/Habbo_Topstory1_2.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/happyaniversary.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/hc_news1.png" class="topstoryimages" style="width: 300px; height: 187px;">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/hejmatematik_celeb.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/horse.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/ikuturso_hiddentreasure_topstory.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/ikuturso_McMurpysTrip_topstory.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/infobus.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/ironik_TopStory_300x187.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/issabrown.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/IT_HB_OL_SONOHORA_030408_topstory_01.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/IT_HB_OL_SONOHORA_030408_topstory_02.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/IT_HB_OL_SONOHORA_030408_topstory_03.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/jansale_1_plastic.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/jansale_1_plastic.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/jansale_3_lodge.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/jansale_4_pura.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/jansale_5_area.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/jansale_6_mode.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/JP_Sky_TS_v1.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/JP_Smile_TopStory_v1.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/kingcorp_300x187_A.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/kingcorp_300x187_B.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/KIR_Topstory.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/limitednews.png" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/madball_TS_1_teaser.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/madball_TS_2_action.gif" class="topstoryimages">
    <img src="{url}/static/topstory/" class="topstoryimages">
```

And the CSS:

```
.topstoryimages {
    width: 300px; 
    height: 187px;
}

img:hover {
    display: block
}

.titel {
    background-color: #9DA2A3;
    font-family: Geneva, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.midden p {
    background-color: #9DA2A3;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

img {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

What I want is that when I am hovering over an image, the image name gets displayed over the image itself. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `title` attribute.

```
<img src="{url}/static/topstory/1atap.gif" class="topstoryimages" title="image 1">
```

When you hover over the image and do not move the mouse a tooltip will show up with the title text.

If you want to be able to copy the tooltip, you can use libraries such as [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/). Working example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLmwxv

Comment: That worked, but I want to like have an overlay and then have the name of the file, so I can easily copy the name.

Comment: @Matthijs_210, Check the edit. I added an example where you can copy the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to adjust your code a bit, but I have a CSS-only solution here:

http://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/VjbbNJ

In this example you use a data attribute (I chose `data-title`) on the `figure` element, and apply a `::after` pseudo-class to create a semi-transparent black box at the bottom of the figure, pulling in `attr(data-title)` for the content.

I tried to eliminate the need for a wrapper, but `<img>` has limitations on the use of pseudo-classes like `::before` and `::after`